# keyboard overlapping UITextField in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, keyboard, swift4

i am trying to handle the scrolling of UITextField to avoid the keyboard to overlap it. [Click here to view  current OUTPUT i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBWuo.gif) ][StoryBoard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JugV1.jpg). I tried to scroll the view when i click on the last textfield ..ie password field. When i click on the password field, only the email field ie the 2nd one is scrolling up. No scroll occur ion the first and last field. How can i solve this issue?

`

```
//
//  ViewController.swift


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // Begin
        switch textField.tag {
        case 0...1:
            print("DO NOTHING")
        default:
            print("Do Scroll")

            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:100) , animated: true)
        }

    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // End
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)

    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
         // Return

        if textField.tag == 0
        {
            email.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else if textField.tag == 1
        {
            password.becomeFirstResponder()

        }
        else if textField.tag == 2
        {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()

        }
        return true
    }


}
```

`

Comment: check that all textfields are exists on scrollview.

Comment: yes it exists....

Comment: can you add screenshot of uiview hierarchy in storyboard ?

Comment: Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU4dB.png

Comment: you need add all field inside the scrollview . it is not exists now .

Comment: U r right. But i just fixed that. But yet again the same issue.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JugV1.jpg

Comment: Put all the 3 fields inside that scroll view... Yet the same issue.. Not no animation is working.. Just before this editing as u see the earlier OUTPUT gif, the email field is rising up. But now all the 3 fields are static

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I've had this problem for about 3 days now its driving me insane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you really want to handle the logic yourself, I recommend you give [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) a try!

It's a simple CocoaPod library that you import and enable in your appDelegate and well... that's all.

It's a codeless library so you really don't have to think about it ever again as it takes over and handles the repositioning of every textfields in the entire application.

Comment: Thanks. It's a great library. No Scrollview!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all textfield to scrollview as below.

[image]

Comment: This points to your local directory, upload it to e. g. Imgur.

Comment: Put all the 3 fields inside that scroll view... Yet the same issue.. Not no animation is working.. Just before this editing as u see the earlier OUTPUT gif, the email field is rising up. But now all the 3 fields are static –

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions of the keyboard-overlap problem both here on StackOverflow and on YouTube. They all are variations of editing event handling. For lazy and time-restrained folks (like me), I would recommend just to use a fixed-height footer (a View with or without content) on the bottom of a scroll view. I usually place there different kinds of disclaimers and help information. This footer will always "push" your textview above the keyboard.